# Why are major email providers separating the username and password forms?

Tags: outlook.com, google, login, yahoo

The trend started with Hotmail, then Gmail and Yahoo followed it. You enter only email address first, then press Next button and a new form appears for the password.

Previously, there was a single form with **email** and **password** fields and a **sign in** or **log in** button. Facebook still goes this way.

**Main question:**

1. Why are they doing this?

**Bonus Questions:**

2. Is there a particular terminology for this kind of behavior?
3. Is there a special feature in Javascript/HTML that easily enables such forms?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I see that lot's of other websites are now following suit. Anyone has any clue why? Or is this a documented way of setting up the login screen?